# Sharing realm between containing app and extension

Tags: swift, cocoapods, realm, ios-extensions

I am sharing the realm between containing app and extension (custom Keyboard), and it works ok on simulator, but when I'm trying to run this app on the real device I have the following error:

> Cannot load underlying module for 'RealmSwift'

It's kinda strange that it is not an issue with simulator but ok. Let's add *pods.framework* to **Link Binary With Libraries** for my extension.

> .../Pods/Bolts/Bolts/Common/BFCancellationTokenRegistration.h:19:1:
>   Duplicate interface definition for class
>   'BFCancellationTokenRegistration'

OK. Let's remove it.

> Cannot load underlying module for 'RealmSwift'

Can't argue that. Let's try to add *RealmSwift.framework* to the extension.

> .../Pods/Bolts/Bolts/Common/BFCancellationTokenRegistration.h:19:1:
>   Duplicate interface definition for class
>   'BFCancellationTokenRegistration'

OK. After several iterations there are several *Pods.framework* in my project folder and *RealmSwift.framework* too. Let's remove them all except one *Pods.framework*. Let's change target membership for this framework to the app and the extension.

> .../Pods/Bolts/Bolts/Common/BFCancellationTokenRegistration.h:19:1:
>   Duplicate interface definition for class
>   'BFCancellationTokenRegistration'

and

> Cannot load underlying module for 'RealmSwift'

together.

How could this be fixed?

Update: I am using Realm and Parse cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

It should just be a matter of creating a second section in your `Podfile` to let you specify the dependencies for your app extension as well as your main app.

```
target 'MyApp' do
   pod 'RealmSwift'
end

target 'MyAppExtension' do
   pod 'RealmSwift'
end
```

CocoaPods does a lot of extra steps in setting up the dependencies and installing them into your target at compile time, so I don't think simply copying `Pods.framework` to the extensions build steps will work.

If you've got multiple references to the same files floating around, then it may be a good idea to completely delete every CocoaPods-related file/folder from your project, and running `pod install` again to make sure it's all set up again properly.

Let me know how you go!

Comment: thanks. i tried to do that, but there was another bunch of errors, so I ended up with creating a new project from scratch and migrating my source code there.

Comment: Hi @lithium, did could you solve the problem? I have the same issue

Comment: yeah, I created the new project from scratch, and it was ok after that. Not the solution I want to recommend but it worked for me.

Comment: Hi, @lithium I tried to create the new project from scratch but still not working, thanks anyway T_T